# Sensor for detect moving with device

Tags: android, android-sensors, sensormanager

Hi I make app in which I use camera and I need to detect in which side is phone moving (left,rigth,up or down) all sensor I have tried just return moving around axis.

So If I have camera and I will move phone to right/left/up/down how to detect it?

Answer (score 0):

You can you the linear accelerometer to detect which direction the user is moving. This page has all the details you will need. There a few sample projects you can have a look at as well.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-accel